# How can I remove the auto float placeholder bug?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, autocomplete, placeholder

When I focus my cursor on the textbox, it shows me a list of suggestions. The problem is that while it show, if I scroll my web page, the entire list scrolls on the page. I have attached a screenshot of this bug. Can some one help me, how to resolve this bug?

Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not the best solution, but you can turn off input field autocomplete - `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: Yeah, sorry you didn`t mention that you are making and email templates.